# How to refactor a code redundancy in the map method using React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, refactoring

The following is the code, using React.js where I call the arrays of swapi (StarWars API) 10 characters each and their description per page inside of

> results0 - results4

```
const CardList = ({ results0, results1, results2, results3, results4 }) => {
  return(
    <Fragment>
    {
```

The following is where the repetitive code begins. results1 ...results4 have the same `.map` method used and returns the same Card information.

```
 results0.map((people, i) => {
      return (
        <Card
          key={i}
          name={results0[i].name}
          skin_color={results0[i].skin_color}
          eye_color={results0[i].eye_color}
          birth_year={results0[i].birth_year}
          gender={results0[i].gender}
        />
      );
    })

result1.map(same values)=>{same function} ...result4.map(same values)=>{same function},

  
     }
     </Fragment>      
     );  
  }; 
export default CardList;
```

Is there a way to shorten the code?

Comment: `{ results0, results1, results2, results3, results4 }` this looks very much like a list to me. Why are these 5 properties and not an array itself?

Comment: Other than shortening the code, is there anything else you're trying to achieve? The question seems broad/opinion-based.

Comment: remove code tags for text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can combine all the arrays and do the map in one step like this

```js
const CardList = ({ results0, results1, results2, results3, results4 }) => {
    return (
        <Fragment>
            {[...results0, ...results1, ...results2, ...results3, ...results4].map((result, i) =>
                (<Card
                    key={i}
                    name={result.name}
                    skin_color={result.skin_color}
                    eye_color={result.eye_color}
                    birth_year={result.birth_year}
                    gender={rresult.gender}
                />))
            }
        </Fragment>
    );
};
export default CardList;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, if the callbacks are identical, factor them out into a utility function, remember to use the current value of the array::map callback

```
const renderPerson = (person, i) => (
  <Card
    key={i}
    name={person.name}
    skin_color={person.skin_color}
    eye_color={person.eye_color}
    birth_year={person.birth_year}
    gender={person.gender}
  />
);
```

This can be further reduced using object destructuring

```
const renderPerson = ({ birth_year, eye_color, gender, name, skin_color }, i) => (
  <Card
    key={i}
    name={name}
    skin_color={skin_color}
    eye_color={eye_color}
    birth_year={birth_year}
    gender={gender}
  />
);
```

Now you've reduced your code to a more manageable

```
results0.map(renderPerson)
results1.map(renderPerson)
results2.map(renderPerson)
results3.map(renderPerson)
results4.map(renderPerson)
```

But you've still some repetition, you can dump the 5 result props into an array and also map them

```
[results0, results1, results2, results3, results4].map((result, i) => (
  <Fragment key={i}>
    {result.map(renderPerson)}
  </Fragment>
))
```

Comment: Tested both answers and they both perfectly fine. Wanted to vote them up, but can't see any changes. Well, anyways I appreciate both answers and I will study both. Peace be for both of yous! Cheers!